# Collection-Type Attached Properties

Tags: c#, binding, uwp, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I would like to extend `FrameworkElement` elements like the `Button` class by collection-type attached property that collect `DependencyObjects`.

The difficulty is that the bindings to the collection items do not work: No debug nor runtime error shows up but the bound source gets never called.

I noted that the collection-type attached property does not inherit from class `DependencyObject`.

I guess the `DataContext` property will be inherited by any child `DependencyObject` object (as long as the parent is also a `DependencyObject` object). As the collection-type attached property does not inherit from `DependencyObject` the `DataContext` property inheritance does not occur.

1. I wonder why instances of `DependencyObject` can inherit the `DataContext` property as `DataContext` is a property defined in `FrameworkElement`? How does the `DependencyObject` manage the `DataContext` lookup?
2. Why does specifying the binding source with `ElementName=PageName` not work as well (e.g. `{Binding MyProperty="{Binding DataContext.PropertySource1, ElementName=PageName}`)? If the `DependencyObject` is also responsible for `ElementName` lookups, how does it do it?
3. Is there a UWP collection that inherits `DependencyObject`? (In WPF there is `FreezableCollection<T>` class but I couldn't find a pendant in the UWP environment.)

The XAML markup below shows an example extension, where the `Binding` does not work.

```
<Button Name="Button">
    <ext:MyExtension.MyCollection>
        <ext:MyDependencyObject MyProperty="{Binding PropertySource1}"/>
        <ext:MyDependencyObject MyProperty="{Binding PropertySource1}"/> 
    </ext:MyExtension.MyCollection>
</Button>
```

If I do the following extension for non-collection-type attached properties the binding can be resolved correctly.

```
<Button Name="Button">
    <ext:MyExtension.MyProperty>
        <ext:MyDependencyObject MyProperty="{Binding PropertySource1}"/>
    </ext:MyExtension.MyProperty>
</Button>
```

The code below shows a sample collection-type attached property implementation. Consider the attached property class also contains a definition for a non-colleciton-type attached property (which works correctly with binding).

```
public class MyDependencyObject: DependencyObject
{
    public object MyProperty
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty , value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(object), typeof(MyProperty), null);
}

public class MyPropertyCollection : ObservableCollection<MyDependencyObject> { }

public static class MyExtension
{
    // Collection-type AttachedProperty with DependencyObject items

    public static MyPropertyCollection GetMyPropertyCollection(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        MyPropertyCollection collection = (MyPropertyCollection )obj.GetValue(MyCollectionProperty );
        if (collection == null)
        {
            collection = new MyPropertyCollection();

            collection.CollectionChanged +=
                (sender, e) =>
                {
                    //intiailization of elements possible
                };


            obj.SetValue(MappingsProperty, collection);
        }

        return collection;
    }

    public static void SetMyPropertyCollection(DependencyObject obj, MyPropertyCollection value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyCollectionProperty , value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyCollection", typeof(MyPropertyCollection), typeof(MyExtension), null);


    // DependencyObject-type AttachedProperty

    public static MyProperty GetMapping(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (MyProperty )obj.GetValue(MyPropertyProperty );
    }

    public static void SetMapping(DependencyObject obj, MyProperty value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty , value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyProperty", typeof(MyDependencyObject), typeof(MyExtension), null);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF it's possible via using `FreezableCollection<T>` or via inheriting from the `Freezable` class, `IList<T>` and `IList`:

1. Inherit it from `DependencyObject` because there are no way to access two required methods of the `DependencyObject`, but `Freezable` has a wrapper around them.
2. Implement `IList<T>` and `IList` as you want.
3. When adding a new element to the collection call `OnFreezablePropertyChanged(null, newItem)`.
4. When removing an element from it call `OnFreezablePropertyChanged(item, null)`.

The `OnFreezablePropertyChanged` method internally will call two methods of `DependencyObject` to provide or remove the inheritance context ([source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Freezable.cs,679)).

But in UWP there is no `Freezable` and there are no such methods, so until Windows 10.0.10240.0 it isn't possible. But if you are targeting v10.0.10240.0 or later you should use [`DependencyObjectCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobjectcollection) which is made for behaviors.

> The purpose of the DependencyObjectCollection class is mainly to support the tooling and portability of behaviors. Behaviors are a technique for defining certain basic interactions of a UI element entirely in XAML, without requiring an event handler and code-behind.

So in UWP and WPF the inheritance context can be provided to children only if they are logical/visual children or they are dependency property values. And because of that the `Binding` with set `ElementName` doesn't work when it is used in your case. The `ElementName` property is used to resolve an object at runtime when the binding is attached to the dependency object and not at compile time.

UWP bindings work like WPF bindings so for example see [`ElementObjectRef.GetObject`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/ObjectRef.cs,95d8f22eef89181b,references) from the second platform.

Comment: DependencyObjectCollection in combination with its event handler VectorChangedEventHandler worked very well. Thank you. 

If it's not too much effort, would you please answer the other questions too, as I'd like to know what's happening in the background when resolving the bindings.

Comment: @Chris Yep, sure. I plan to expand the answer, but in my spare time (: